# How to Register ColdFusion 8

Tags: coldfusion

ColdFusion Studio 4.5 or ColdFusion 8 from Allaire (not Macromedia, not Adobe).
IT support is trying to install on a Windows 7 machine (so I can get off my XP box).
Company will not update the software.

Installation will not complete, as the install is trying to connect to a ColdFusion registration server, which apparently is no longer 'up'.
Phone number does not work either.  (Yes, I saw the 20 year party the Allaire brothers are throwing.)

Is there any way to do this?

I have already waited nearly a year for them to get the software together I need so I can go to W7!

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're not connected to the internet when you install, the installer shouldn't attempt to call home. Even then it should timeout eventually. Have you tried to run the installer in WinXP compatibility mode? I've got CF8 running OK here, but it's as an EAR install on a CF9 multi-server install. I don't recall having tried to install it stand-alone on Win7.  NB: CF8 is an Adobe product. Allaire's last CF version was 4.5, and Macromedia's was CFMX 7. That said, CF8 has been EOL since Aug 2014, so you'll not get any support from Adobe anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question but what about using Railo as an alternative to legacy Allaire ColdFusion?

http://www.getrailo.org/

Comment: Not looking for a new server.  There is at least one other user with Cold Fusion installed.
A new CFML editor may work.
I will check with our IT guy on the first answer when he gets back.